# Ionic 4 Angular 8 - Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: angular, runtime-error, global, ionic4, angular8

M upgrading my ionic app from Ionic 3 to 4. But I got this error.

[image]

I know there are many solutions available in other forums. But they didn't work for me.

I tried `(window as any).global = window;` but it didn't work.

And I also tried to add `Dragula`. It didn't work either.

What i am missing? What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

as ***@richardsengers*** answer

> https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/678#issuecomment-389106098

include this

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

In your `polyfills.ts` file

Answer (score 3):

If anyone here with the same issue using Ionic 5 with Angular 10,

Install globalthis:

```
npm install globalthis
```

Add:

```
import 'globalthis/auto';
```

in polyfills.ts

Note : Adding (window as any).global = window;
In polyfills.ts file didn't work in my case

Comment: Thank you! life saver. This only happened to me on the android app, the iOS app was ok

Comment: Yeah @C_Ogoo this issue happens only in android.